# Can't access WCF service after versioning service contracts

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I'm having trouble figuring out an issue with a WCF service that has appeared after I have implemented a "v2" contract to it to extend functionality. Everything builds fine but when I try to access the service in the browser I just get told that it cannot connect. When I try to add it as a service reference I get a similar message regarding connection issues. However, when I remove the extended contract's endpoint from the config file, and leave the previous "v1" version intact, it works fine.

Here is the "v1" contract:

```
namespace Company.Services.Ticketing.Retail.Contracts
{
    [ServiceContract(Name = "OutletReportingContract_v1", Namespace = "https://enterprise.company.ie/Services/Retail")]
    public interface IOutletReportingContract_v1
    {
        /* methods */
    }
}
```

And here is the "v2" contract:

```
namespace Company.Services.Ticketing.Retail.Contracts
{
    [ServiceContract(Name = "OutletReportingContract_v2", Namespace = "https://enterprise.company.ie/Services/Retail")]
    public interface IOutletReportingContract_v2 : IOutletReportingContract_v1
    {
        /* methods */
    }
}
```

Here are the endpoints in the Web.config:

```
  <service name="Company.Services.Ticketing.Retail.OutletService" behaviorConfiguration="Public">
    <endpoint address="1" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Standard" name="OutletReportingContract_v1" 
        contract="Company.Services.Ticketing.Retail.Contracts.IOutletReportingContract_v1" />
    <endpoint address="2" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Standard" name="OutletReportingContract_v2" 
        contract="Company.Services.Ticketing.Retail.Contracts.IOutletReportingContract_v2" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" name="IMetadataExchange" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

And here is the error message that appears in the event viewer:

> WebHost failed to process a request.
>    Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/28075619
>    Exception: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): There was no channel actively listening at 'https://phil-pc.company.local/Services/Retail/OutletService.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening. ---> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no channel actively listening at 'https://phil-pc.company.local/Services/Retail/OutletService.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.
>      at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
>      at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
>    Process Name: w3wp
>    Process ID: 8148

A bit stumped now and would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your services declaration in web.config.

Assuming your implementation classes are named OutletService_v1 & OutletService_v2 you should end up with something like that:

```html
<services>
  <service name="Company.Services.Ticketing.Retail.OutletService_v1" behaviorConfiguration="Public">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Standard" contract="Company.Services.Ticketing.Retail.Contracts.IOutletReportingContract_v1" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" name="IMetadataExchange" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>

  <service name="Company.Services.Ticketing.Retail.OutletService_v2" behaviorConfiguration="Public">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Standard" contract="Company.Services.Ticketing.Retail.Contracts.IOutletReportingContract_v2" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" name="IMetadataExchange" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply!

I actually forgot to add the fact the the v2 contract inherits from the v1 contract, I have update my post to reflect that.

Regarding your solution, the thing is that the format I have used in my post works fine for another service, and there are no obvious differences in the implementation.